# Center wide div in Safari

Tags: ios, css, safari, html5-canvas, alignment

I have a wide canvas and I can't center it in Safari. On any browser except Safari it works perfect.

```css
.center {
  padding: 0;
  margin: auto;
  display: block;
  height: 100vh;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%);
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%);
}
```

After damiano celent advice I modified code like this

```
left: 50vw;
```

Looks like it works on iphone 4s but doesn't work on iphone 6

Comment: How is this a javascript problem?

Comment: Add height:100% after height:100vh, I suspect it's the vh proerty, but am not sure.

Comment: I tried in both safari and chrome, and I don't see any difference; what I am getting in both is the canvas fills both width and height of the window. what are you trying to do exactly?

Comment: In Safari we see only small part of  the scene https://i.imgur.com/9sKD2Qs.png while  in Chrome it's OK

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I made a little hack to avoid the problem we can not solve.

Animated canvas is here:

```
.center{  
position:static;
    padding: 0;
    margin: auto;
    display: block;
    height: 100vh;
  z-index: 2;

    }
```

While background image has this options:

```
background-size: cover;
background-position: 
bottom center;
background-image: url('images/fon.jpg');
background-color:rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
margin:0px;
overflow: hidden
```

Answer (score 1):

I got it to work in both safari and chrome with this.

```
var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas'),
context = canvas.getContext('2d');

drawBackground();

function drawBackground()
{
  var img = new Image();
  img.src = 'tunnel.jpeg';

  //when image loads
  img.onload = function(){

    //put in center
    context.drawImage(img, canvas.width/2 - img.width/2, canvas.height/2 - img.height/2);
  }
}
```

Hope it works for you!